# perl Event::Lib cpan install failed

Tags: perl

I am trying to build Event::Lib and the build fails because it can't find event.h. I am running this on a Mac with OSX 10.15.4 with Perl v5.28.2. What package do I need to install that will provide me with the correct header?
thanks

Comment: Have you got libevent itself installed?

Comment: Not just libevent, but the "devel" files for it. When using a package manage, the `.h` files are usually in a separate package. I don't know about OS/X

Comment: I installed libevent and now I have a a different error. I have a number of the following error:  Lib.xs:692:33: error: no member named 'ev_arg' in 'struct event'
            SvREFCNT_dec((SV*)args->ev.ev_arg);

Comment: what I mean by build is cpan Event::Lib. That builds and installs the module.

Comment: "_build is cpan_" --- OK, I see.  Looks like perhaps some version mismatch?

Comment: Event::Lib is an abandoned module last updated 13 years ago. Why do you want to use that? Generally, when it comes to ancient code, you are on your own. Even then, remember to show us the error messages you get.